# Q: ffmpeg drawtext "localtime" video filter - display in custom format

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having issues escaping ':' symbol and displaying localtime in a hms(HH:MM:SS) format for overlay over a Live input(MPEG-TS) which is then pushed out as Live output - I've fumbled my way to displaying '[localtime](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion)' in a format which achieves about half of what I'm trying to get to, the code sample of that is:

```
ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT -vf drawtext="fontsize=90:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%H %M %S}'" -f LIVE_OUTPUT
```

What it achieves is that it displays local time in a "HH MM SS" format instead of "HH:MM:SS"...

---

I did try escaping ':' by writing it like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT -vf drawtext="fontsize=90:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%H\\:%M\\:%S}'" -f LIVE_OUTPUT
```

and this:

```
ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT -vf drawtext="fontsize=90:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%H\:%M\:%S}'" -f LIVE_OUTPUT
```

as well as like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT -vf drawtext="fontsize=90:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%H \: %M \: %S}'" -f LIVE_OUTPUT
```

But none of the above helped as it returns different errors because ffmpeg tries to either parse '%H' '%M' and '%S' as multiple, separate arguments for localtime (localtime then complains that it can only accept x1 argument at most), or ffmpeg complains that there are loose '%' characters near "H" ... clearly I'm not escaping it correctly or my argument order is incorrect...

Comment: Anyone looking for answers on how to display timecode or elapsed time, here's the answer you're looking for: [Display Timecode and/or Elapsed time in a overlay text](http://superuser.com/a/575935/484497)

Comment: Found some hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19810519/2855434 ...

When written it like this:

    ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT -vf drawtext="expansion=none:fontsize=90:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%H\:%M\:%S}'" -f LIVE_OUTPUT

I end up displaying '%{localtime:%H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original requirement of displaying HH:MM:SS can be achieved as follows

```
ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT \
-vf drawtext="fontsize=90:fontcolor=white: \
              fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%X}'" \
-f LIVE_OUTPUT
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That's exactly what I was trying to achieve! I was so lost I was starting to look for overcomplicated ways to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

I have worked for days and finally solved this problem, it turns out the solution is simple, just add more \ until you finally got it.

```
ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -i LIVE_INPUT -vf "drawtext=fontsize=90:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='%{localtime\\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}'" -f LIVE_OUTPUT
```